# Uploading to Drive via browser

Tags: google-drive-api, google-cloud-platform, drive

I am using a variation of the following cors-script to drag and drop a file to Google Drive: https://github.com/googledrive/cors-upload-sample. Here is a live example of it: http://googledrive.github.io/cors-upload-sample/.

However, I would like to pre-authenticate the person who visits the page so that they are always uploading into **my** Drive account and they **do not need to sign in**. In other words, either hard-code my account credentials or authenticate whenever a user loads the page to get the oauth token (or whatever else is needed).

How would this be done?

Comment: For example, is this method useful for you? https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/2f16f467c94612dc83920a3158614d95 This is the method for uploading local files using user's browser by Web Apps. In this case, users are not required to login and authorize. Each upload is done as owner. If this was not useful, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for the suggestion -- how would that apply to uploading it via the cors example above?

Comment: You want to make each user login, make users upload files to your Google Drive. Is my understanding correct? After it makes each user login, if you want to make them upload, when you deploy Web Apps, it sets "Execute the app as:" and "Who has access to the app:" as "User accessing the web app" and "Anyone", respectively. By this, the login screen displays for each user. After logged in, the your script is run. Here, it makes user's files upload to your Drive using the script. If I misunderstand your question, please tell me.

Comment: @Tanaike no I don't want the user to be able to log in. I just want them to be able to drop a file onto the page (that's it) and it uploads it directly to my Google Drive.

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood your question. When you want to make users upload files without login, you can use [the sample script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/2f16f467c94612dc83920a3158614d95).

Comment: @Tanaike this is from the Drive API webpage: `>Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests. No other authorization protocols are supported. If your application uses Google Sign-In, some aspects of authorization are handled for you.

>All requests to the Drive API must be authorized by an authenticated user.`

Comment: @Tanaike https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Do you want to make users upload using Drive API? If you want to do this, my sample script might not be suitable for your situation. My sample script makes users upload files to owner's Google Drive without the authorization.